# Почему четвёртый блок выходит из сетки, при уменьшении экрана?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Я пользуюсь `bootstrap3`. Блок выходит из сетки:

[image: Как блок выходит из сетки]

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
        <div class="frame"><img src="img/creioane.jpg" alt="alt"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
        <div class="frame"><img src="img/christmas.jpg" alt="alt"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
        <div class="frame"><img src="img/hallween.jpg" alt="alt"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
        <div class="frame"><img src="img/pomgranate.jpg" alt="alt"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.frame {
    margin-bottom: 22px;
}

.frame img {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #D6D6D6;
}
```

Comment: http://codepen.io/bustexz/pen/yOxpZp?editors=1100
все нормально, проблема видимо у вас, может какой стиль добавляет отступ

Comment: Да, скиньте CSS классов col-md-3 col-xs-6

Comment: добавьте реальные картинки в вопрос. ибо дело, вероятно, именно в них - в их размере, в частности. а лучше, используйте сниппет  - значек <> в верхней панели редактирования ответа. тогда можно будет рассуждать предметно

Comment: я по экспериментировал с размерами, очередь картинок.

Comment: @lexxl вставлял картинки, даже большие, это ни на что не влияло

Comment: @DimaCalmis скинь из инспектора стили на эти блоки

Comment: оставил только img { width: 100%;} результат тот же.

Comment: @lexxl прав, у вас в скрине первая картинка по высоте больше чем вторая, поэтому 3 и 4 уезжают, выровняйте их по высоте и будет вам  счастье :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В дополнение к уже сказанному:

Чтобы не зависеть от размера картинок добавьте после первых двух картинок [блок с clearfix и настройкой видимости](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-responsive-resets).

```
<div class="clearfix visible-xs-block visible-sm-block"></div>
```

Тогда даже с "неправильной" картинкой получится два ровных ряда:

```css
.frame {
    margin-bottom: 22px;
}

.frame img {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #D6D6D6;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
            <div class="frame"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x151" alt="alt"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
            <div class="frame"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="alt"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix visible-xs-block visible-sm-block"></div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
            <div class="frame"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="alt"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
            <div class="frame"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="alt"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Дело в высоте первой картинки. Она на 1 пиксель больше, чем соседняя. Обратите на размеры картинок в примере ниже:

```css
.frame {
    margin-bottom: 22px;
}

.frame img {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #D6D6D6;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
            <div class="frame"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x151" alt="alt"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
            <div class="frame"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="alt"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
            <div class="frame"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="alt"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
            <div class="frame"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="alt"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Потому что padding и border у картинки. Попробуйте его убрать. Скорее всего border причина.

Comment: http://codepen.io/bustexz/pen/yOxpZp?editors=1100 привел же пример, в нем все в порядке, что то внешнее действует на блоки, тут код нормальный

Comment: оставил только img { width: 100%;} результат тот же.